# How to change the title of a button in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I installed the commerce backoffice module. In the store products list having a quick edit button, actually I need to change the Quick edit title of a button to Quick look, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try [hook_page_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7).

```
function my_modulename_page_alter(&$page) {
  //find your button in $page variable and change its text.
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to alter the text on the form button.